# how to unenroll user programmatically

Tags: moodle

i want to unenrol user from a course in moodle ,i want to know there is any in built function like

```
unenrol_user($userid,$courseid)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$instances = $DB->get_records('enrol', array('courseid' => $courseid));
foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    $plugin = enrol_get_plugin($instance->enrol);
    $plugin->unenrol_user($instance, $userid);
}
```

Moodle supports multiple enrollment methods (e.g. 'manual', 'guest', etc.,) via plugins. This loops through the enrollment methods configured for the course and tries to unenroll the user using each.

Library: lib/enrollib.php